# Build a project using gradle FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I am trying to build an opensource project using gradle, but when I run the "gradle clean" command within my local repository directory the following error message appears.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:

  > Build file '/home/muhammad/OpenSource/iotsys/iotsys/build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:

  > A problem occurred evaluating root project 'iotsys'.
  >   Plugin with id 'maven-publish' not found.
- Try:

  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> BUILD FAILED

my "build.gradle" file look like this

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'at.ac.tuwien.auto.iotsys'
version = '0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

repositories(){
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo url: 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/', name: 'JBoss Releases'
    mavenRepo url: 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/', name: 'JBoss Public' }}
```

I am new to gradle and maven. Can any one please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: I agree either wrong version of gradle or weird char that doesn't show up in the file. The message is saying it is failing at line 3, I added the same thing to my build.gradle and ran the clean target and got a success.

Comment: Oh also aren't you missing a } for your all projects?

Comment: sorry for delayed response,
i am using gradle 1.1 which is suggested by the project organization 
and i also pastd only the part of the file here due to problem with posting whole file

Comment: The `maven-publish` plugin was only introduced in Gradle 1.4. TU Wien shouldn't be using 1.1 (or even 1.4) in 2014. :-)

Answer (score -2):

The solution is very very simple you just have to run the studio with administrator privileges..

STEPS : -

1. Right click on the studio icon.
2. Run as Administrator.

That's it Enjoy..!